# robolectric throws FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Tags: android, unit-testing, fragment, robolectric

I run a specific unit-test:

```
      @Rule
      public ActivityScenarioRule<FragmentUtilActivity> activityScenarioRule2 =
          new ActivityScenarioRule<>(FragmentUtilActivity.class);

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
... //not related to activityScenarioRule2
      }

      @Test
      @Config(qualifiers = "sw600dp")
      public void myTest() {

        activityScenarioRule2
            .getScenario()
            .onActivity(
                activity ->
                    standaloneAccountMenuDialogFragment.showNow(
                        activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "FragmentTag"));

        assertThat(...);
      }
```

I see the @after code is called (with one breakpoint which turned into two breakpoints)

[image: image.png]

and I get this runtime error:

```
FragmentManager is already executing transactions
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1551)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1611)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:137)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
```

How can it be if I use activityScenario which is defined once and managed by  `@Rule` annotation? It fails only for this specific test

Any ideas what can it be?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `showNow()` instead of just `show()`?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this issue with Robolectric and ActivityScenario, and it appears to be a race condition where the fragment isn't attached by the time we get to it.  There's a warning about this in the default (LEGACY) LooperMode, which is what is used if a mode isn't specified.  More details on that in the javadoc [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/annotations/src/main/java/org/robolectric/annotation/LooperMode.java#L44)

Try adding @LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED) to the top of your test class, which has some improvements on the Looper behavior.   You may also need to add a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call in the teardown method.

Another workaround, if that doesn't help, is to add sdk=[27] to the config at the top of the test class like this-
@Config(sdk = [27])

There are more details on this issue - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3698

Comment: I had the same error message with FragmentScenario and a fragment where I committed a fragment transaction in onViewCreated(). Works fine when running the app, but breaks in the test. Adding the LooperMode annotation to the test fixed the issue!